# Why can `s => x.Append(s)` can be passed as an Action<string> but `x.Append` can't?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I noticed something strange when trying to pass a `StringBuilder`'s `Append` method to a function that took an `Action<string>`.

```
public void DoStuff(Action<string> handler)
{
    // Do stuff, call handler("data");
}
```

For testing purposes, I just want to write the data into a `StringBuilder`, so I tried to call it like this:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
DoStuff(output.Append);
```

However, this gives a compile error, because the `Append` method does not match the required signature (it returns a reference back to the `StringBuilder`, not void as my method wants):

> 'System.Text.StringBuilder System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(string)' has the wrong return type

Without thinking, I changed the code to this:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
DoStuff(s => output.Append(s));
```

This compiled fine.

Then I got confused; realising that `s => output.Append(s)` should also return the `StringBuilder`, aren't they the same?

So, why does this work? Why can `s => output.Append(s)` have the return value discarded silently, yet `output.Append` cannot?

Comment: Note that [`DoStuff(AddressOf output.Append)` would work in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531336.aspx)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`s => output.Append(s)` creates a new lambda expression, which is inferred (from the context) to have a return type of `void`.
Therefore, the value of the expression body is ignored.
This is compiled to a separate method that calls `Append()` and returns void (this exactly matching the delegate)

In contrast, when you attempt to convert a method group to a delegate, the conversion must match exactly.

The spec (§6.5) says:

> Specifically, an anonymous function F is compatible with a delegate type D provided:
>
> - If the body of F is an expression, and either D has a void return type or F is async and D has the return type Task, then when each parameter of F is given the type of the corresponding parameter in D, the body of F is a valid expression (wrt §7) that would be permitted as a statement-expression (§8.6).

Comment: I'm confused how that is not translated to this with a multi-line lambda: `s => { return output.Append(s); }`. I would assume they would be equal.

Comment: @gunr2171: No; it is inferred to not return anything/

Comment: So you are saying that _because_, and only because it's an `Action`, it ignores the return value?

Comment: Seems like "=> (expression)" has more magic than expected. I wonder if maybe during design/dev they realised discarding return values would be clunky without it?

Comment: @gunr2171 Lambda expressions in C# are always inferred based on their usage.  `s => output.Append( s )` has no meaning by itself.  It only has meaning in a place where the compiler can infer the type.  This is because lambda expressions can also be used with expression trees such as `Expression<Action<string>> expr = s => output.Append( s )`.  This infers the lambda to be a type that isn't even a delegate.

Comment: This is also why statements such as `var f = s => output.Append( s );` are a compile error.  The compiler cannot infer the expression type, so use of `var` is incorrect.

Comment: @Kyle: That compile error isn't because of the return type ambiguity, but because even for a particular signature, there can be multiple delegate types matching the signature.  For example, `MethodInvoker` and `Action`, or `Predicate<T>` and `Func<T,bool>`.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny: See my edit for the relevant spec quote.

Comment: @BenVoigt I never claimed it was due to return type ambiguitiy.  Lambda expressions are not limited to representing delegate types, either, which is the point I'm trying to make.  This is what I mean when I say a lambda expression by itself has no meaning (or, rather, has no type).